# Angular Auth Guard after Login does not get observable informations

Tags: javascript, angular, authentication, guard

I implemented a login in angular. 
It works well, but I like to redirect after successfully authentication.

The redirect does not work after receiving the user from server. 
If I refresh my page and use the login, it works.

I receive an object from my webservice and save it to "localStorage".
I use a BehaviourSubject to observe my current user.

If I press 'login' i run into auth guard, but the auth guard does not know the user. (its null)

What is my mistake?

**Auth.guard.ts**

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
    constructor(
        private router: Router,
        private authenticationService: AuthService
    ) { }

    canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
        console.log(this.authenticationService.currentUserValue);
        if (this.authenticationService.currentUserValue) {
          return true;
        }
        // not logged in so redirect to login page with the return url
        this.router.navigate(['/entrance/login'], { queryParams: { returnUrl: state.url } });
        return false;
    }
}
```

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {
  private currentUserSubject: BehaviorSubject<User>;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.currentUserSubject = new BehaviorSubject<User>(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser')));
}

public get currentUserValue(): User {
    return this.currentUserSubject.value;
}


login(username: string, password: string) {
    return this.http.post<User>('/api/auth', { username, password }).pipe(map(user => {
        // login successful if there's a jwt token in the response
        if (user && user.token) {
            // store user details and jwt token in local storage to keep user logged in between page refreshes
            localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(user));
            this.currentUserSubject.next(user);
        }

        return user;
    }));
}
```

```
    this.authService.login(email, password).pipe(first()).subscribe(data => {
        this.router.navigate([this.returnUrl]);
    });
```

I like to redirect directly after login without refresh.

You see any mistakes?

Comment: where do you define `user`?

Comment: in same module; user  is working fine i think.

Comment: the auth service doesnt have `user` defined, so that why its undefined

Comment: no; in auth guard its undefined after login. after refresh the object is set.

Comment: I think since you are not passing any predicate for the `first()` filter, you are receiving the `http.post` observable as data. This might result in the navigation being called before the API call completes. Have you verified the order in which the API call and navigation is getting called ?

Comment: @Andréw without seeing that code, we dont know that, going by the code you have provided, its undefined

Comment: Okay, i try again: The "user" is set in the auth service If I login. After login I like to redirect to to the "returnUrl / StartUrl". Then the auth guard get called. The Auth guard access to "currentUserSubject.value". in the auth service its set (if I say console.log(currentUserSubject.value) but in the auth guard its undefined. If I refresh the page, its set in the auth guard and its redirect correctly.